# Нужно сделать интересный media запрос в CSS

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries

Есть у меня лендинг и он использует что-то по типу fullpage. При работе с адаптивностью возникла одна проблема, мне нужно, чтобы при расширении 1024x1366(iPad Pro) применялись уже более мобильные стили (это я сделал):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
```

Но мне также нужно, чтобы при расширении устройства 1024x768(это ноутбук) эти стили не работали, как можно модифицировать этот запрос под эту ситуацию?
Пробовал так:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and not (device-height: 768px)
```

Но он почему-то теперь не работает на iPad Pro.

Comment: почитайте что такое user agent

Comment: @MaximLensky, я в общем понимаю, что такое user-agent, но не особо понимаю, как его можно использовать в media запросах

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/277777 вот посмотрите

Comment: Так это решение на JS, меня больше интересует можно ли реализовать все это на чистом CSS

Comment: на css? на врядли

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для iPad - `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait)`.

Можно так же попробовать `aspect-ratio`.

Answer (score 2):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 1366px)
```

А ещё можно одновременно указать min и max.

И вообще, так подгонять под устройство - это какой-то идиотизм. Почему при большом экране iPad Pro не показывать нормальную версию?

Comment: Очень много элементов, которые просто лишнее на мобильном устройстве (даже для iPad)